# dynamic variable name in spring form:label

Tags: java, spring, jsp-tags

I'm using spring tag library and have a  `form:form` with `commandName=${myCommandName}` inside of which I have a textarea

```
<form:textarea path="settingsMap['${myVar}.myVal'].value" />
```

it works as expected (i.e. display value from that path in text area) but when I use label instead

```
<form:label path="settingsMap['${myVar}.myVal'].value" />
```

it doesn't work as intended.

I searched for it and found that for label the value to be shown must be placed between

```
<form:label></form:label>
```

so I tried something like

`<form:label 
path="settingsMap['${myVar}.myVal'].value">command.settingsMap['${myVar}.myVal'].value
</form:label>` but it is giving blank value.

Need some help

Comment: You need to put the that value on your model and reference it that way.